# Script to Re-Join Domain with Powershell

Tags: powershell, dns, vmware

Sorry for my English.

I have VMs on VMWare ESXi running Windows 7.  All of the machines are in domain, but sometimes they leave domain, so I need to rejoin it.  I wrote simple script to do this:

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("mydomain\user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force))
Add-Computer -WorkGroupName TEMP -Credential $credential
Add-Computer -DomainName "mydomain" -Credential $credential
Restart-Computer
```

But it doesn't work; I have this error:

```
Add-Computer : This command cannot be executed on target computer('') due to following error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
At C:\Tools\Re-Join.ps1:2 char:13
+ Add-Computer <<<<  -WorkGroupName TEMP -Credential $credential
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand<br>
```

If I manually join 'workgroup' and then run the script all works fine.

Comment: Why are you adding the computer to a workgroup before adding it to the domain?  Just add it to the domain.

Comment: Computer like in domain. So I need to leave it and join for the second time. In any case just adding computer to domain causes same error.

Comment: dejoin from a domain needs restar anyways

Comment: If I do next steps:
1. Join workgroup using Control Panel;
2. Join Domain using powershell or GUI;
3. Restart;
all works fine
But If I am trying to join workgroup with powershell I have error.

Comment: By the way, in case you didn't know already, the reason your machines sometimes leave the domain is probably because you restore snapshots. Machines in domains periodically change their machine passwords with the domain controller, so if a snapshot is restored, it will be restored to a state with an old password. This behavior can be disabled on the domain controller if you want, but it's bad for security (so what you're doing with rejoining is better, though a little awkward :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script I use to join domain:

```
$computer = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup("cloud.com" , "PASSWORD HERE", "USER", $null, 3)
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add an unjoin before the join, you won't need to reboot before rejoining the domain:

```
$computer.UnJoinDomainOrWorkGroup("PASSWORD HERE", "USER", 0)
```